# Populating a nested List

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, multidimensional-array

I want to add my buttons in this list

```
List<List<Button>> buttonss = new List<List<Button>>();
```

This is how i create my buttons:

```
Button[][] buttons;
```

In the method(also try to populate the list but it is not right):

```
for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
    {
       for ( int c = 0; c < col; c++)
           {
             buttons[r][c] = new Button();
             buttonss.Add(buttons[r][c]);
           }
    }
```

How can i populate this list using this button array (my array has to be `Button[][]` and not `Button[,]` as it will make my life easier when I do other stuff like xml serialization

Comment: I do hope you did `buttons = new Button[][row];` and `buttons[r] = new Button[col];` first

Comment: @Nolonar I love that your comment makes me feel like the fate of the world rests on his proper instantiation.  Mainly because it does.  :S

Comment: @Nolonar Yes all that is done i have not pasted the whole code

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're trying to store this two separate ways, but if you *really* need to then you need to initialize each inner array and list:

```
buttons = new Button[row][];
for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
{ 
   buttons[r] = new Button[col];
   List<Button> rowList = new List<Button>();
   buttonss.Add(rowList);    
   for (int c = 0; c < col; c++)
   {
     buttons[r][c] = new Button();
     rowList.Add(buttons[r][c]);
   }
}
```

Another way to do it would just be to *store* in a jagged array and *convert* to a list (or vice-versa):

```
// From List<List> to Jagged Array
buttons = buttonss.Select(b=>b.ToArray()).ToArray();

// From Jagged Array to List<List>
buttonss = buttons.Select(b=>b.ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ `Select`:

```
buttonss = buttons.Select(b => b.ToList()).ToList();
```